# Multiple lists in python into excel

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

How would I combined multiples columns into a single column in excel using pandas in Python?

```
a=[5,4,3,2,5,4,6,9,8,4,3,2,6]
b=[11,12,1,2,11,9,11,11,4,12,0,2,11]
c=[9,5,4,6,10,5,12,13,14,10,3,6.1,5]

from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'Stimulus Time': a  c, 'Reaction Time': b})

df.to_excel('case2.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Reaction Time  Stimulus Time
0              11              5
1              12              4
2               1              3
3               2              2
4              11              5
5               9              4
6              11              6
7              11              9
8               4              8
9              12              4
10              0              3
11              2              2
12             11              6
```

However I need the output in the following format:

```
Reaction Time             Stimulus Time

From 0 to 11              5
From 1 to 12              4
From 2 to 1               3
From 3 to 2               2
.......
.......
........
```

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using an intermediate list which converts the start and end times to a string.

e.g.

```
d = ["From "+str(i)+" to "+ str(j) for i,j in zip(range(0,len(b)),b)]
```